# How can I completely unsubscribe from getting push notifications?

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my application I have implemented Push Notification functionality.
I added a button for the user, which allows him to turn off the notification completely. However it doesn't work as I excpected. Here's the code snippet:

From MainActivity:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("test_topic");

        ((SwitchCompat)findViewById(R.id.notification_switch)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Switch activated ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("test_topic");
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Switch deactivated ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().unsubscribeFromTopic("test_topic");

                        new Thread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }).start();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

FirebaseMessagingService class to handle the message:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public static String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getName();
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage){
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.e(TAG, "onMessageReceived() --> " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());

    }

//    @Override
//    public void onNewToken(String s) {
//        super.onNewToken(s);
//        Log.e(TAG, "onNewToken() --> " + s);
//    }

}
```

When I try to send a notification using topic I don't get any notification. If I send the notification to all devices with the app, I still get the notification. How can I completely prevent my app from getting notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Unregistration and Unsubscription

There are three methods a client app can use to stop receiving messages and/or topic subscriptions from the app server:

InstanceID deleteToken() with audience set to the app server's sender ID and scope set to GCM. This stops messages (including topic messages) from a specific app server

InstanceID deleteID(). This stops messages from all previous registrations and topic subscriptions for all app servers

GCMPubSub unsubscribe(). This stops topic messages from the specific topic of the app server

For FCM, it should be the FirebaseInstanceId.

Comment: Can you please explain more what is the difference between deleteID() and deleteToken() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `setAutoInitEnabled(false)` before `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId()`.
When enabled, FCM generates a registration token on app startup if there is no valid one and **generates a new token when it is deleted** (**which prevents deleteInstanceId() from stopping the periodic sending of data**). This setting is persisted across app restarts and overrides the setting specified in your manifest.

**By default, FCM auto-initialization is enabled**.

For more information: [FirebaseMessaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging.html#isAutoInitEnabled())

Comment: I tried to use `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().setAutoInitEnabled(false);` before calling `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();`, but then `onNewToken(String s)` was called and I got a new token.

Comment: Right, I think `setAutoInitEnabled` only will solve getting new token when the app starts.. maybe `@Override` the  `onNewToken` method and read some "`isNotificationEnabled`" preference to know if you need to call `super.onNewToken(s)` or ignore.. not sure if it'll work.